# POST encryption/hash decryption

Tags: encryption, hash

I have an https packet where I am trying to figure out what the website is using to encrypt or hash my POST data.

I have it in an email:pass format and this is what I am being returned.

Email:Pass before hash:
aaaa@aaaa.aaa:aaaaaaaa

After Hash that is posted is this value:
email=6464646445646464642b646464&password=6464646464646464

I have looked around to try and find the right charmap but I was unable to do so.

If anyone has an idea please let me know thanks.

Comment: There was a previous answer that indicated that it is just the binary value, XORed with 05h and then hex encoded, which seems to be correct to me. However, as this is not a programming question, it's rather off topic.